# git on Mac: replace Apple XCode CLI git with symbolic link to latest git install?

Tags: macos, git

XCode CLI installer puts a copy of git in /usr/bin

Reinstalling the latest git from git-scm.com put git in /usr/local/git/bin/git

Can you tell me if there are any known problems with doing the following:

```
sudo rm /usr/bin/git
ln -s /usr/local/git/bin/git /usr/bin/git
```

Comment: Why not just `PATH=/usr/local/git/bin:$PATH` in your `.profile` or `.bash_profile`?

Comment: I, at least, would _rename_ the original `/usr/bin/git`, just in case.

Comment: Shouldn't be a problem if thats what you want, but as advised above, might be better to back it up!