# Cannot use git from terminal

Tags: macos, git, github

I installed the GitHub UI for OS X from here: https://central.github.com/mac/latest. As part of the installation I get an option to "Install Command Line Tools". On doing so it places the relevant assets under /usr/local/bin. I assumed it would register git in the PATH variable as well so that I could run it from the terminal if needed. However it doesn't work from the terminal, instead if I run 'git' in terminal, I get prompted to install XCode.

Am I assuming something incorrectly here? Also tried installing git from here: http://git-scm.com/download/mac. After the installer completed successfully, I still can't seem to be able to use git from the terminal.

UPDATE: my PATH variable has the following:

/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin

Comment: First, you need to restart bash (e.g. by opening a new terminal) after installing something that modifies the default values of environment variables. Second, what does `echo $PATH` say?

Comment: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin

Comment: Whenever I try and invoke git from the terminal I get the following message with a prompt: xcode-select: note: no developer tools were found at '/Applications/Xcode.app', requesting install. Choose an option in the dialog to download the command line developer tools.

Comment: Any chance you can try and put `/usr/local/git/bin` first in the `PATH`? (just in one shell session, to see how XCode and git react then)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As mentioned in "[git on Mac: replace Apple XCode CLI git with symbolic link to latest git install?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18179367/6309)", it dpeends on the order of the folders in the `PATH` environment variable.

> - XCode CLI installer puts a copy of git in `/usr/bin`
> - Reinstalling the latest git from git-scm.com put git in `/usr/local/git/bin/git`

If git command line is installed in `/usr/local/git/bin`, make sure to put that in first:

```
PATH=/usr/local/git/bin:$PATH
```

Answer (score 2):

Just download these tools running command in terminal:

```
xcode-select --install
```

If it doesn't help you try to download them manually form apple developer site:
https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?=command%20line%20tools#

It helped me.

Comment: i agree, non of command line solutions worked for me, i installed manually and worked https://developer.apple.com/download/all/?q=command%20line%20tools

Answer (score 0):

This command worked for me

```
sudo xcode-select -switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```