# jenkins does not find git on mac

Tags: macos, jenkins

Jenkins building a simple hello world app fails with this command

```
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git init /Users/jenkins/workspace/helloworld" returned status code 1:
stdout: 
stderr: xcode-select: note: no developer tools were found at '/Applications/Xcode.app', requesting install. Choose an option in the dialog to download the command line developer tools.

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2430)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2360)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2356)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommand(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1916)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$5.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:988)
    ... 11 more
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] }
Cloning repository https://github.com/xxx/demo_qmake_hello_world.git
 > git init /Users/jenkins/workspace/helloworld # timeout=10
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
Finished: FAILURE
```

Obviously the Jenkins java SSH connection does not find `git` on my mac. 
But why? Yes the execution context seems to be different, not the same PATH...But adding the PATH to the node's ENV did not work. Other people had the same issues, and only got this answer, but it just does not work.

[image]

---

**Update**

There is an option on the node to specify Git Tool location. I added it like this.
[image]

Git seems to be found now. But now the permissions are unsufficient.

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/usr/local/git/bin" (in directory "/Users/jenkins/workspace/helloworld"): error=13, Permission denied
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:252)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:221)
    at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:936)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:454)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2423)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=13, Permission denied
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:247)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
    ... 20 more
```

With `ls -la /usr/local/git/bin` I have checked the ownership.
`git` belonged to root, but I have changed it to `jenkins`.

Still this seems not enough, still get the permission error...

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jenkins wheel 5941024 Nov 8 2017 git
```

**Update 2**

The correct path in the Node's tools is `/usr/local/git/bin/git`. That was the problem.

Comment: Have you tried the answers mentioned here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19887445/cannot-use-git-from-terminal

Comment: Also, how do you have git installed? If you want to use the system version you need to install the [XCode developer tools](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2339/_index.html), which is what the error on the top line seems to be saying.

Comment: I have installed git via the official installer from sourceforge. I do not want Xcode on my mac. The goal is to build all in docker containers on my mac. Jenkins does not start a docker container but tries to check out on mac host, but this is another question...

Comment: And I have tried the answers from your linked question. `/usr/local/git/bin:$PATH` did nothing.

Answer (score 0):

`which git` - is the command to find git location on mac